# Add new items to existing object model react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

junior trying to learn. I have the following function.

```
overlay = (rulersOnLine) => {
    const mainRulers = {
        AB: <Box sx={SX.ruler10} />,
        CD: <Box sx={SX.ruler20} />,
    };

    let skeleton;
    let newRulersOnLine = [];

    rulersOnLine.map((value, index) => {
        if (value === 1) {
            skeleton = {
                name: 'A' + index + 'B' + index,
                node: <Box sx={SX.ruler10} style={{opacity: 1}} />,
            };
        }
    });

    return mainRulers;
};
```

My main object is

```
const mainRulers = {
    AB: <Box sx={SX.ruler10} />,
    CD: <Box sx={SX.ruler20} />,
};
```

I want to add more items **dynamic** ex:

`A1B1: <Box sx={SX.ruler20} />`

**rulersOnLine** is an array made of 0,1 (max 4 elem).

**How can I add new items (under the given form) to the main object?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly that you want to add it to `mainRulers`, You can do like

```
overlay = (rulersOnLine) => {
  const mainRulers = {
    AB: <Box sx={SX.ruler10} />,
    CD: <Box sx={SX.ruler20} />,
  };

  rulersOnLine.forEach((value, index) => {
    if (value === 1) {
      mainRulers[`A${index}B${index}`] = (
        <Box sx={SX.ruler10} style={{ opacity: 1 }} />
      );
    }
  });

  return mainRulers;
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Exactly what I needed.